# HttpClient.SendAsync exeption : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, httpclient, asp.net-core-2.0

I've got an asp.net core 2.0 web app (Running using Kestrel) with following controller :

```
public IActionResult GetUpdateList(string apiCode, int softwareId, [FromBody] List<SoftwareFile> updateFiles)
{
    try
    {
        var stream = SoftwareUpdateFilesHandler.GetUpdateZipFileStream(updateFiles, softwareId);
        return File(stream.BaseStream, "application/octet-stream", "UpdateFile");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return NotFound(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

and this code on my client :

```
public async static Task<byte[]> GetUpdateAsync(string apiCode, int softwareId, List<SoftwareFile> updatefiles)
{
    try
    {
        StringContent content = null;
        if (updatefiles != null && updatefiles.Count > 0)
        {
            content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatefiles));
            content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
        }
        string address = $"{baseAddress}GetUpdate?softwareId={softwareId}";
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), address);
        request.Content = content;
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        return responseContent;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when code reaches to `httpClient.SendAsync` code hangs and after a few seconds client app crashes and I get this exception : `The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly`

All of this works fine when I test my code in local but when I publish code and try to call `GetUpdateList` I get exception.

Odd thing about this is I can't handle exception in my catch block. Somehow catch block doesn't catch this exception and I can see exception in application crash.

Comment: Where is the get GetUpdateZipFileStream implementation, can you provide that as well please?